# Measure of how far a basis is from orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

here's a problem that is a bit vaguely defined. Let the $m\times m$ matrix $U$ have columns $U_i$ that form a basis in $R^m$. Assume these columns have unit length, $|U_i|=1$. The matrix $R = U^\top U$ then contains scalar products, $R_{ij} = U_i^\top U_j$. Obviously, $R$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite (we assume definite).

The question is: is there a standard measure of "how far" this basis is from being orthogonal?

The transformation $V = U R^{-1/2}$ constructs an orthonormal basis $V$ (since $V^\top V = I$; $R^{-1/2}$ is the inverse of the symmetric square root of $R$ -- could also be a Cholesky factor). Thus one may suspect that a "standard measure of distance from orthogonality" should use in $R$ in some way... The condition number of $R$ maybe? Any pointers appreciated!

/Tobias

Comment: Why do you *assume definite*? Since $U$ columns form a basis, $U$ is regular, and so is $U^TU$.

Comment: To me it seems that any norm of $U^T U - I$ is a reasonable measure of non-orthogonality.

Comment: Why $R$ positive definite? I guess it was because I wanted $R^{-1/2}$ to be well defined.

Comment: @Ian Also maybe the eigenvalues of $U^TU$, or equivalently the singular values of $U$ (for instance, the quotient of the max to the min singular value). When $U$ is orthogonal, this quotient is $1$, when it's not it's higher. Of course it's related to the 2-norm.

Comment: Actually, a clearer measure would probably not be one number but rather the vector of all singular values of $U$. The closer this vector is to the vector containing all $1$s, the "more orthogonal" $U$ is.

Comment: $U^\top U - I$ is a good idea! It is a matrix however, not a scalar. Maybe its norm, $\| U^\top U - I\|$ ?

Comment: @Tobias My point is, it is allways definite, no need to assume. This is so because $x^TU^TUx=||Ux||^2$ can be null only if $x=0$, since $U$ is regular.

Comment: @Tobias I think the matrix 2-norm of $U^T U - I$ is $\max_i |\sigma_i^2-1|$ where $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of $U$. So this is a good scalar measure, though a vector measure would be better. (For instance, maybe you have some huge number $N$ of columns, the vast majority of them are already orthogonal, but a few of them are far from orthogonal. A scalar measure can't detect this situation.)

Comment: @Jean-Claude: Thanks, I see what you mean.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, it will be $\max |\sigma_i^2-1|$. The ratio $\sigma_\max^2 / \sigma_\min^2$ in a previous comment is the condition number (mentioned in the original posting). This number is unbounded though, as opposed to $\max |\sigma_i^2-1|$. The latter measure is nicer from that perspective.

Comment: @Tobias The condition number of $U$ would be fine too. That's what I allude to above. This is exactly the quotient of max to min eigenvalue of $U^TU$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Almost: the condition number of $U$ is the square root of the ratio of eigenvalues of $U^T U$. But it achieves the point.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That says what I said; recall that the singular values of $U^T U$ are the squares of those of $U$.

Comment: @Ian You're right of course, sorry. I often forget this square root to get the singular values, shame on me !